# How can I grab frame only when there is plant/flower featured frame in the real time camera vision?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, opencv, python

The camera is fitted in front of the bot. I want to classify two plants. Now there will be other objects too, in front of the bot. Now instead of processing every frame from the video, I want to just grab a frame of only the plant and then try to classify the plant. The idea is to just avoid processing the other objects (non-plants).

For Example: Is it possible to use Canny Edge Detection(or any other method) to vaguely understand the features of (plants/flowers) and later grab that frame to classify(for this I am using VGG16)??

Comment: I don’t understand. You have to grab the frame to see if there is a plant in it or not.

Comment: yeah, you are correct I want to just grab that frame that has plants. Later use that frame to classify. @CrisLuengo

Comment: If I understand right you want to process every frame but only trigger the advanced processing if the primitive processung shows that there is a plant? Well... object detection in uncontrolled environment is a hard task, so your chances are bad, unless you choose a potent platform that performs an advanced object detection algorithm in real-time. Have a look at tiny yolo v4 or mobile-net SSD.

Comment: A suggestion would be to reduce the fps if your focus is on being economical from a computational perspective and run an object detector on every frame, trained only with images of your plants.

Comment: Thanks, @Micka .  Actually, mine is a classification problem. Is there any way to grab a plant from the video without performing the object detection? I even thought of a custom cascade classifier but again that will be detection.

Comment: thanks, @RobertMoga. Is there any method without using the object detector, but can be solved with image processing? It is ok, even if the results are not good.

Comment: @Konda deciding whether and where there is an object in the image IS a detection (or classification+localization) task. You can still try to implement a cheap & simple specialized detector. What kind of processing ressources do you want to spend for the detection task? How many fps do you have to reach for this detection? If there were cheap and simple well working general purpose object detection algorithms, people wouldnt need the expensive DNN detectors, would they?